# Help with what I believe is an ablative

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, ablative, phaedrus

> Conferre nostris tu potes te laudibus?
>   Moror inter aras, templa perlustro deum;
>   ubi immolatur, exta praegusto omnia;

(Phaedrus, "[Formica et Musca](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0118%3Abook%3D4%3Apoem%3D24)")

I understand it to mean "Are YOU able to compare by our praises" but in the context maybe praises should be another word, maybe reputation or what we are known for. Hoping for some enlightenment.

Comment: Sorry, of course it's potes!!  But "Exta praegusto deum" which to me sounds like " I have a foretaste of the gods intestines lol

Comment: Where is this quote from? It often helps parsing it if we know exactly where it came from.

Comment: http://aesopus.pbworks.com/w/page/1472846/phaedrus081

Answer (score 2):

**Te** in this sentence means 'the ant.'

"Are you able *(potes)* to compare **yourself** *(te)* with our praises?"  --and this is followed by other boasts.

"And where there is sacrifice, I am the first to taste the gods' chitterlings."

It's tricky to translate it to show the entrails are delicacies put out for the gods! Praegustator tastes the Emperor's food to make sure it's safe. Here's a version of the revised text,

> I loiter amongst the altars,  busy myself with the temples of the gods; //
>   And where there is sacrifice, I am the first to taste every chitterling.